# iwlwifi 5Ghz internet randomly lags for seconds

Tags: debian, intel, iwlwifi

We recently upgrade our internet provider which now comes with 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz wifi. I can connect properly on 2.4Ghz while on 5Ghz I am experiencing random "lags" in the connection. More specifically, the network manager is not disconnecting from the router however to refresh a page in a browser when the lag strikes it needs 7-30 seconds. Some times ssh connection is dropped too. This is happening in a random manner but usually every 3-5 minutes.
I tried to change the 5Ghz channel with no luck. The rest of the devices in the house are not experiencing any issues.

I 've already tried to reinstall Intel 3160 drives from backports as well as to reinstall the linux-image with no luck. I 've also disabled wifi.powersave to wlan0 with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve or debug this issue?

These are some system information:

uname -a:

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u5 (2018-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux (Debian stretch)
```

lshw -C network:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 93
       serial: 34:e6:ad:be:63:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.9.0-8-amd64 firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:49 memory:c1000000-c1001fff
```

iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BRA****"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.56 GHz  Access Point: F8:AB:05:00:1E:DE   
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:125   Missed beacon:0
```

ifconfig:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::36e6:adff:febe:6365  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:8109:a3c0:55af:36e6:adff:febe:6365  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 34:e6:ad:be:63:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 415816  bytes 507186123 (483.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 144134  bytes 31353570 (29.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisi
```

lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

modinfo iwlwifi:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-lc-a0--26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--26.ucode
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A370sv*sd00001030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002526sv*sd00001030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000031DCsv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
[...]
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.0-8-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Comment: I don’t know the solution to your problem but can tell you that I’m experiencing the same problem on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Comment: So I am not alone. Is your inteface made by Intel? If yes, which product?

Comment: Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78); Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]; Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi; Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that problem was the wifi adapter driver. I successfully solved the issue by upgrading the Kernel to the latest version (4.18) that is included in the stretch-backports repository.

Apt should have backports sources enabled

> for Debian Stretch, append the following in /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

then install the kernel:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -t stretch-backports install linux-image-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

and reboot to load the new kernel.

Comment: Not really solved my problem. I have the same exact issue with Debian Buster and I already have Linux 4.19 installed. I still get those strange lag strikes for a couple of seconds almost every link I try to open.

Comment: Same than @DavidTamar, after update to Buster.
Current kernel
Linux antix1 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u1 (2019-07-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Since that fixes I neved had issues again with the wifi. Try to install intel-microcode from backports as well as the latest firmware for your adapter.